# Agregar Pestañas a detalles

Tags: android

Llevo todo el dia intentando agregar un tablayout a una activity de detalles, la cual se abre con un click del list view, me pueden ayudar por favor?.

Detailpartidos.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.ramon.rafelcf.Cadete.CalendarioCad;
import com.ramon.rafelcf.Cadete.Tab.TabJorCad;
import com.ramon.rafelcf.Campos.FragGridCampos;
import com.ramon.rafelcf.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static com.ramon.rafelcf.R.id.backdrop;
import static com.ramon.rafelcf.R.id.tv_Equipo_Local;
import static com.ramon.rafelcf.R.id.tv_Equipo_Visi;
import static com.ramon.rafelcf.R.id.tv_Fecha;
import static com.ramon.rafelcf.R.id.tv_Resultado;
import static com.ramon.rafelcf.R.id.tv_esc_local;
import static com.ramon.rafelcf.R.id.tv_esc_visi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class DetailPartidos extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TabLayout pestanas;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private TextView r_Local;
    private TextView fecha;
    private TextView e_local;
    private TextView e_visi;

    private String recibir;

    private String TAG = DetailPartidos.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get info JSON
    private static String url = "http://www.--";
    private static String url_num_jornada = "Jornada";
    private static String url_id_cod = "Id_Partido";
    private static String url_id_local = "Id_Local";
    private static String url_id_visi = "Id_Visi";

    private static String url1= "http://www.--";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList, tit, tar, gol;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_partidos);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            insertarTabs(container);

            // Setear adaptador al viewpager.
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            poblarViewPager(viewPager);
            pestanas.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


            pestanas.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
            //pestanas.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
            //pestanas.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        }
    }

    private void insertarTabs(ViewGroup container) {
        View padre = (View) container.getParent();
        pestanas = new TabLayout(getApplicationContext());
        pestanas.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }

    private void poblarViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        DetailPartidos.AdaptadorSecciones adapter = new DetailPartidos.AdaptadorSecciones(getFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new FragGridCampos(), ("Todos"));
        //adapter.addFragment(new FragGridCampos_Valencia(), ("Valencia"));
        //adapter.addFragment(new FragGridCampos_Castellon(), ("Castellon"));
        //adapter.addFragment(new FragGridCampos_Alicante(), ("Alicante"));

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        String id_jor = getIntent().getStringExtra("Jornada");
        url_num_jornada = id_jor;

        String id_cod = getIntent().getStringExtra("Id_Partido");
        url_id_cod = id_cod;

        String id_local = getIntent().getStringExtra("Id_Local");
        url_id_local = id_local;

        String id_visi = getIntent().getStringExtra("Id_Visi");
        url_id_visi = id_visi;

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        tit = new ArrayList<>();
        tar = new ArrayList<>();
        gol = new ArrayList<>();



        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        final ImageView Esc_local = (ImageView) findViewById(tv_esc_local);
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(getIntent().getStringExtra("Esc_Local"))
                .fitCenter()
                //.transform(new CircularTransform(DetailActivity.this))
                //.override(3000, 3000)
                .into(Esc_local);

        final ImageView Esc_visi = (ImageView) findViewById(tv_esc_visi);
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(getIntent().getStringExtra("Esc_Visi"))
                .fitCenter()
                //.transform(new CircularTransform(DetailActivity.this))
                //.override(3000, 3000)
                .into(Esc_visi);

        /*jornada = (TextView) findViewById(tv_jornada);
        recibir_jornada = getIntent().getStringExtra("Jornada");
        jornada.setText(recibir_jornada); */

        r_Local = (TextView) findViewById(tv_Resultado);
        recibir = getIntent().getStringExtra("R_Local");
        r_Local.setText(recibir);

        fecha = (TextView) findViewById(tv_Fecha);
        recibir = getIntent().getStringExtra("Fecha");
        fecha.setText(recibir);

        e_local = (TextView) findViewById(tv_Equipo_Local);
        recibir = getIntent().getStringExtra("E_local");
        e_local.setText(recibir);

        e_visi = (TextView) findViewById(tv_Equipo_Visi);
        recibir = getIntent().getStringExtra("E_visi");
        e_visi.setText(recibir);

        /*dorsal_local = (TextView) findViewById(textView4);
        /*recibir = getIntent().getStringExtra("Id_Local");
        /*dorsal_local.setText(recibir);

        /*id_visi = (TextView) findViewById(textView5);
        recibir2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Id_Visi");
        id_visi.setText(recibir2);

        id_partido = (TextView) findViewById(textView6);
        recibir3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Id_Partido");
        id_partido.setText(recibir3);*/

        //recibir = getIntent().getStringExtra("Imagen");
        String Name = ("Jornada - ")+intent.getStringExtra("Jornada");

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(Name);

        //collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getTitle());
        collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);
        collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);

        //Margenes para el titulo left, top, right, bottom
        collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleMargin(125, 0, 0, 75);
        //collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleMarginTop(170);

        loadBackdrop();
    }

    public class AdaptadorSecciones extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> fragmentos = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> titulosFragmentos = new ArrayList<>();

        public AdaptadorSecciones(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentos.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentos.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            fragmentos.add(fragment);
            titulosFragmentos.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return titulosFragmentos.get(position);
        }
    }

    private void loadBackdrop() {
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(backdrop);
        Glide.with(this).load(recibir).centerCrop().into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetailPartidos.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Por favor espere...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url+url_id_cod+"&idl="+url_id_local+"&idl="+url_id_visi);

            String jsonStr1 = sh.makeServiceCall(url1+url_num_jornada+"&cmp=135&idl="+url_id_local+"&idv="+url_id_visi);

            //"http://www.ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/server.php?action=getActa&tmp=2016/2017&jor=22&cmp=135&idl=0201045201&idv=0202112211

            //String jsonStr1 = sh.makeServiceCall(url1+"22&cmp=135&idl="+url_id_local+"&idv="+url_id_visi);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr1);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(jsonStr1);

                    JSONObject arbi = jsonObj.getJSONObject("infoGeneral");



                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                    String arbitro = arbi.getString("arbitroPrincipal");


                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                    contact.put("arbitro", arbitro);

                    contactList.add(contact);
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////




            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( DetailPartidos.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.arbitro_row,
                    new String[]{"arbitro"}, new int[]{R.id.arbitro});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

detail_partidos.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:layout_height="170dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/local"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

            <ImageView
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/friends_red"
                android:id="@+id/tv_esc_local"
                android:background="@drawable/degradado"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Rafelbuñol C.F Rafelbu de ñ ol C.F"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_Equipo_Local"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/resultado"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:text="0 - 0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_Resultado"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:text="No disponible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_Fecha"
                android:textColor="@color/color_light"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/visitante"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <ImageView
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/friends_red"
                android:id="@+id/tv_esc_visi"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/degradado"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Rafelbuñol C.F Rafelbuñol C.FRafelbuñol C.F "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_Equipo_Visi"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" >
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>



</LinearLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Datos del club"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_nombre_campo" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_poblacion"
                    android:text="Poblacion"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_telefono"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Telefono"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="E-mail" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_web"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Web" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/columColor"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/call_out"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_llamar"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:onClick="llamar" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mail"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_mail"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:onClick="mail" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/internet"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_url"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:onClick="abrir_url" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cursor"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_navegar"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:onClick="navegar" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Y los errores que me da son:

> Error:(89, 26) error: cannot find symbol variable container
>   Error:(113, 109) error: incompatible types:
>   android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Gracias

Comment: Hola Rafa, un gusto saber de tí nuevamente, (como que todo el día :| ) , usa el método correspondiente a la clase de soporte que es: getSupportFragmentManager() , saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas usar `getSupportFragmentManager()` en lugar de `getFragmentManager()`, ya que estas usando la clase `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` :

```
//DetailPartidos.AdaptadorSecciones adapter = new DetailPartidos.AdaptadorSecciones(getFragmentManager());
DetailPartidos.AdaptadorSecciones adapter = new DetailPartidos.AdaptadorSecciones(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

---

En cuanto que poner como `container`:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_partidos);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            insertarTabs(container);
...
...
```

En realidad es una vista que desees sea el contenedor, por ejemplo puede ser un `LinearLayout` que tengas en tu layout, debes obtener la referencia para posteriormente agregar los elementos.

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

insertarTabs(container);
```

Comment: como siempre la primera en contestar, Si eso es una cosa, pero en la linea  insertarTabs(container); la palabra container tambien esta en rojo y no se que poner

Comment: Ah es un ejemplo que obtuviste de internet, entonces no es funcional, de donde lo obtuviste?

Comment: Hermosa programacion creo, entonces, ¿como las puedo añadir?

Comment: Agregué actualización, debes saber que elemento de tu layout detail_partidos.xml, deseas como contenedor.

Comment: findViewbyId en rojo, he añadido un LinearLayout con el id tabs1, dentro el android.support.design.widget.TabLayout y elandroid.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Comment: es findViewById

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57122/discussion-between-rafel-c-f-and-jorgesys).